# can't submit ajaxForm when using method post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this dialog in my javascript containing form with file and hidden input like this

```
form1 = form1 + 
    "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='svScheckPicOtc' accept-charset='utf-8' id='formOTCSCImgUpld' method='post'>" +
    "<input id='fileImageGroup' name='fileImageGroup' type='file' class='globaltextbox' />" +
    "<div id='divResultImgGroup'>" + "<table border='0'><tr><td><div style='height:100px; width:100px; border: 1.8px solid #CCCCCC;'></div></td></tr></table>" + "</div>" +
    "<input id='hidThr_InvNo' name='hidThr_InvNo' type='hidden' value='" + InvNo + "' />" +
    "</form><br>";
```

This is my ajax

```
$('#formOTCSCImgUpld').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal);
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal);
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function(retData) {
        alert(retData);
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal);
        percent.html(percentVal);

        preventDoubleUpload = 1;

        var retDataSplit = retData.split(":=:");

        if (retDataSplit[0] == "validationerrors")
        {
            for (a=1;a < genFieldResets.length;a++)
            {
                    $("#" + genFieldResets[a]).css({"color":"#000000"});
                    $("#" + genFieldResets[a]).css({"font-weight":"normal"});
            }

            var errorText = "";

            for (a=1;a < retDataSplit.length;a++)
            {
                    if (retDataSplit[a] == "error_1")
                    {
                        errorText = errorText + "<li><span style='color:red;'><b>Invalid File or No file selected.</b></span></li>";
                    }
                    else if (retDataSplit[a] == "error_2")
                    {
                        errorText = errorText + "<li><span style='color:red;'><b>File size should not exceed 5MB.</b></span></li>";
                    }
                    else if (retDataSplit[a] == "error_3")
                    {
                        errorText = errorText + "<li><span style='color:red;'><b>Invalid File Format. Please Upload JPG/JPEG image only.</b></span></li>";
                    }
                    else if (retDataSplit[a] == "error_4")
                    {
                        errorText = errorText + "<li><span style='color:red;'><b>Invalid File Extension Name. Please Upload JPG/JPEG image only.</b></span></li>";
                    }
                    else if (retDataSplit[a] == "error_5")
                    {
                        errorText = errorText + "<li><span style='color:red;'><b>You already uploaded an image. Remove the image first in order to upload a new one.</b></span></li>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#" + retDataSplit[a]).css({"color":"#FF0000"});
                        $("#" + retDataSplit[a]).css({"font-weight":"600"});
                    }
            }

            if (errorText == "")
            {
                <!-- altClosePopBox(); -->
                openPUBox("exsmall");
                $("#popbox500x150_content").html(pboxcovers("exsmall") + "<b>You need to Fill-up all the Required Fields correctly to continue.</b>" + "</div>");
            }
            else
            {
                <!-- altClosePopBox(); -->
                openPUBox("small");
                $("#popbox500x300_content").html(pboxcovers("small") + "You have an error in this fields:<br><ul>" + errorText + "</ul>" + "</div>");
            }


            js1101_pboxCloseButtonLock = 1;


            genFieldResets.length = 0;

            genFieldResets = retDataSplit;
        }
        else if (retDataSplit[0] == "success")
        {
            $("#divResultImgGroup").html(retDataSplit[1]);

            $("#fileImageGroup").val('');
            <!-- altClosePopBox(); -->
        }
    },
    error: function(requestObject, error, errorThrown){
        console.log(requestObject);
        console.log(error + ": " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

However, whenever I submit the form triggered from the `onChange` event on `input[type='file']`, I always get error 500. When I change the method to `get`, there are no error thrown. But definitely it won't get the file uploaded.

Note that I am using CodeIgniter and this structure is perfectly working on `view`. What I am trying to do is to implement it inside a dialog/popup.

Comment: how is the submit triggered

Comment: it is triggered by the `onChange` event on `input[type='file']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 500 error is probably from an issue server side. Are you getting any errors in codeigniter?

Comment: But there are no errors when submitting the form from a view, how come there is an error when I put this in a dialog/popup. 
There are no other error except this, saying that the action is not allowed.

Comment: Can you provide any more details on what that 500 error is? My first reaction is that you may have some CSRF issues with your ajax form, but that would produce a 403 instead of a 500 error. Django should be logging the 500 error for you. If you could provide it here, I can help you get to the bottom of this!

Comment: Thank you Sir Jordan. You're right with the CSRF issues. As I am using MVC, I printed out `form_open_multipart` to a JS variable. I expected that only the `<form>` tag would be printed but it also printed out an `input[type='hidden']` containing the csrf encrypted token. Thank you again Sir, and by the way, how can I mark this question as 'already answered'?